# zipkin spring integration error

Tags: spring, zipkin

I'm testing zipkin to spring boot integration but im facing error like below. The error seems to happen when it tries to send message to zipkin server

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Span.isShared()Z
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.ZipkinSpanReporter.convert(ZipkinSpanReporter.java:79) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.ZipkinSpanReporter.report(ZipkinSpanReporter.java:198) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.trace.DefaultTracer.close(DefaultTracer.java:165) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.detachOrCloseSpans(TraceFilter.java:234) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:167) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:590) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:524) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:389) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

here is my pom.xml file. it may be have a problem in version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.terry</groupId>
<artifactId>zipkin-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>zipkin-demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-zipkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and this is my application.yml file
im running zipkin server in same machine with different port

> ```
> server:
>   port: 8081
> spring:
>   application:
>     name: testsleuthzipkin
>   zipkin:
>     baseUrl: http://127.0.0.1:9411/
>   sleuth:
>     sampler:
>       probability: 1.0
> sample:
>   zipkin:
>     enabled: false
> ```

any guide or information are welcomed!

Comment: Could you provide the entire error logs? (these logs are too verbose and sometimes the real error is not easily grasped). Also: are you trying out some broadly available example or is it something you're building from scratch? It'd be great if you could share your code.

Comment: From what you've already provided at the moment, I've noticed a strange `Z` in the end of the first line of error log: `.isShared()Z`. Just by chance, this is not actually in your code base, right?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same error. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just add below, it need to be working,

```
 zipkin:
    sender:
      type: web
    baseUrl:  http://192.168.0.207:9411
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      percentage: 1.0
```